# Javascript merge array of token objects while preserving the structure of text

Tags: javascript

I have a document composed of one or more lines separated by a `\n`. Using the approach showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64032621/detect-exact-words-positions-in-text-in-javascript), it can be represented in terms of sentences, one for line, and tokens for each sentence. So, given a text with two sentences `"Lorem ipsum dolor\nsit amet consectetur"` the `json` representation will look like:

```
{
    "sentences": [{
            "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
            "tokens": [{
                    "word": "Lorem",
                    "characterOffsetBegin": 0,
                    "characterOffsetEnd": 4
                },
                {
                    "word": "ipsum",
                    "characterOffsetBegin": 6,
                    "characterOffsetEnd": 10
                },
                {
                    "word": "dolor",
                    "characterOffsetBegin": 12,
                    "characterOffsetEnd": 16
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "text": "sit amet consectetur",
            "tokens": [{
                    "word": "sit",
                    "characterOffsetBegin": 18,
                    "characterOffsetEnd": 20
                },
                {
                    "word": "amet",
                    "characterOffsetBegin": 22,
                    "characterOffsetEnd": 25
                },
                {
                    "word": "consectetur",
                    "characterOffsetBegin": 28,
                    "characterOffsetEnd": 38
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

where `characterOffsetBegin` and `characterOffsetEnd` are the position of each token in the whole text. Now, assumed that the text has been modified (like in case of a misspelling) like the following:
`"Lorem ipum dolor\nsit aet consetetur"`, the resulting `json` will be

```
{
    "sentences": [{
            "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
            "tokens": [{
                    "word": "Lorem",
                    "characterOffsetBegin": 0,
                    "characterOffsetEnd": 4
                },
                {
                    "word": "ipum",
                    "characterOffsetBegin": 6,
                    "characterOffsetEnd": 10,
                    "suggestion": "ipsum"
                },
                {
                    "word": "dolor",
                    "characterOffsetBegin": 12,
                    "characterOffsetEnd": 16
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "text": "sit amet consectetur",
            "tokens": [{
                    "word": "sit",
                    "characterOffsetBegin": 18,
                    "characterOffsetEnd": 20
                },
                {
                    "word": "aet",
                    "characterOffsetBegin": 22,
                    "characterOffsetEnd": 25,
                    "suggestion": "amet"
                },
                {
                    "word": "consetetur",
                    "characterOffsetBegin": 28,
                    "characterOffsetEnd": 38,
                    "suggestion": "consectetur"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have to map the first json of sentences on the second, while keeping the structure of the whole initial text, adding the extra fields (like `suggestion` in this example), only using `characterOffsetBegin` and `characterOffsetEnd` to match the tokens in each sentence, so, by example, the output for the last token of the last sentence must be

```
{
   "word": "consectetur",
   "characterOffsetBegin": 28,
   "characterOffsetEnd": 38,
   "suggestion": "consectetur"

}
```

Give the solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64109205/758836), how to apply it at this more general case?

Comment: should the characterOffsetEnd not change as well since you have added a character (cascading through the sentence?)

Comment: Correct, but in this case it doesn’t change with the text, since it refers to the initial source text, and not to its changes. So you can use it as a reference.